# Running automated tests on managed extensions in Neo4j 2

Tags: java, neo4j

I would like to setup automated testing for my managed extensions.

I am using CommunityServerBuilder as suggested in this post http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/20/neo4j-testing-an-unmanaged-extension-using-communitserverbuilder/#comments

with versions:

- neo4j 2.1.1
- jersey 2.9

When I try run a test I see this error.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:     
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:211)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have also tried jersey versions 1.17, 1.18 and 1.10 and receive the same error. It only works when I use version 2.0.0 of neo4j but then I receive this other error (and I also want to use the newest version of neo4j so this isn't really an option)

```
Found class org.neo4j.server.database.Database, but interface was expected
```

Neo4j version 2.0.1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been some changes in non-public API from Neo4j 2.0.x -> 2.1.x.

I have created a small project [neo4j-spock-extension](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-spock-extension) providing infrastructure for testing unmanaged extensions. It's currently based on Neo4j 2.0.x and will be updated to Neo4j 2.1.1 shortly. Will amend a comment here when done.

Comment: neo4j-spock-extension 0.4 supports now Neo4j 2.1.x

Comment: Does your project also handle testing managed extensions?  I'm having some trouble figuring out a good way to test those.